# PipAuthenticate@1 task in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

PipAuthenticate@1.” This task requires the artifact feed name and any service connection for an external repository to download packages and set the variable $(PIP_INDEX_URL).

The $(PIP_INDEX_URL) variable contains the URL for the artifact feed that pip install command can use to download Python packages from. the pip command uses the $(PIP_INDEX_URL) as an option in the pip install command (--index-url  option). Although Pip can fetch the dependencies from the artifact feeds, but it fails to fetch or update dependencies from artifact feed upstreams, leading to errors in the pipeline:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httptools==0.6.1 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for httptools==0.6.1

Please Note that:-  httptools in artifact feed is 0.6.0 and httptools==0.6.1 is already exists into artifact feed upstreams and poetry can fetch it and update it using the same value in $(PIP_INDEX_URL) but pip can't.

I was wondering if there anything missing regrading PipAuthenticate@1 so I can make pip install dependencies form artifact feed versions and upstreams without any issues.

Comment: Hi there, may I ask whether the extenal repository that you mentioned is the Azure Artifact feed from another Azure DevOps organization or any other package repository provider? If it is an external feed from another Azure DevOps orgnization, can you please also check if the `Addtional protections when using public package registries` option is enabled in this Organization Settings -> Security -> policies?